# Approval workflow for the page edits

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a lot of pages where critical information is provided to the users. Only a select few have access to edit the pages. I would like to know if there is any way that a supervisor can see and approve the changes made by the contributes before the publishing is done. Like a workflow attached to the page to sent details when a contributor makes changes and once the supervisor approves it the changes made will get saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is publishing web page in SharePoint on premise, but I haven't had any change to check that feature in online.

Here how you do [Require approval of items in a site list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08), under library setting:

1. Set "Require content approval for submitted items?" to Yes
2. Set "Only users who can approve items in the list, and the item author"
3. Give user "Approve Items  -  Approve a minor version of a list item or document." or just set up a SharePoint group with that permission and add that user to the group.

To inform approval, we could create a workflow.

Comment: Thanks Ariwibawa. I was able to do the above skiping  the 3rd step and providing contributed access to the user. I coudnt find "Approve Items  -  Approve a minor version of a list item or document." fom the permission list as shown in the link https://keoftpwu.blob.core.windows.net/ftp/temp/ess0rd3t.nsc.zip

Comment: I usually work with share point designer, When item is created or edited and providing the link to the current list item. in this case the link sent will be the page itself right? and is there any way we can present the changes to the approver  so that they know what they are looking for rather than going through the entire page and figuring out what changes are made to the page. and is it possible for the approvar to approve it directly from the page rather than going to the page library?

Comment: @Rinu I saw your attachment, give user Approve permission that's what they need. Approver can Approve it from the page, is there tab Publish when you open those page? In on premise you can approve that page from there.

Comment: @Rinu I'm afraid I haven't had any idea how to present changes side by side. You can use Page History hopefully that will be enough for your need. http://wiki.plexhosted.com/kb/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013:Page_history_and_versions