# Checked out comment missing from SharePoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

We have a lot of pages where critical information is provided to the users. Only a selected few have access to edit the pages. Supervisor can see and approve the changes made by the contributes before the publishing is done. So in practice, a workflow attached to the page to sent details when a contributor makes changes and once the supervisor approves it the changes made will get saved.

I was able to do all that with the help of the below link
[Approval workflow for the page edits](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/approval-workflow-for-the-page-edits)

But on the SharePoint designer workflow I had to show the "check in comments"
which is not available in the current item lookup. Is it like this by design? Can we make "check in comments" available on the SharePoint Designer?

I can see approver comments but not check in comments in the SharePoint Designer Workflow under current item lookup